# How to keep android device log from not being cleared?

Tags: android, logging

I want to dump all logs out to test a long usage of my app, maybe 2-3 days, but the logs seem to be cleared out while running after a long time.

How can I keep the logs?

I do not want to connect my device with eclipse all the day, I want the log just keep for me, like store it in the sd card for further check.

Comment: The logcat log is a 64KB ring buffer, so eventually older entries are going to be overwritten by newer ones. You will need to capture the log periodically yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the eclipse log use the apps like 'log viewer'. I think that app can solve your issue. I think the log will remain until you clear the log manually in 'log viewer'. I just downloaded it today morning and still has the logs of actions I performed just after I switched on the device.

Answer (score 2):

I had same requirement for my application. By default there is `logcat` process that tracks logs up to around 64kb (depends on device).

You can start your own `logcat` process using `adb shell` with some custom arguments. For example:

```
adb shell logcat -f /mnt/sdcard/large.log -r 100 -n 10
```

This will save up to 1mb of logs evenly distributed among 10 files (large.log, large.log.0, larget.log.1, etc.);

The next step is to launch `logcat` from your application:

```java
String [] args = new String[] { Logcat, "-v", "threadtime", 
                                "-f", logFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                                "-r", Integer.toString(sizePerFile),
                                "-n", Integer.toString(rotationCount),
                                "*:"+filter}; 

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

So now your app may start saving logs. But you should be careful not to enable this in your production versions of application (or at least make this opt-in feature).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dumping the log to a file?

`adb logcat > log.txt`